# GJS: Gtk.TextView key-press-event does not work

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell, gnome-3, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I am trying to create simple gtk application for gnome-shell using gjs.

Its window contains Gtk.TextView only and I want to process events when user is typing.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/gjs

var Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk;

function MainWindow () {
    this._init ();
}

MainWindow.prototype = {
    _init: function () {
        this.window = new Gtk.Window ({
            title: "Just Calculator",
            window_position: Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER,
            default_height: 400,
            default_width: 440,
        });

        //this.window.show ();
        this.window.connect ("hide", Gtk.main_quit);
        this.window.connect ("delete-event", function () {
            Gtk.main_quit();
            return true;
        });

        this.textbox = new Gtk.TextView();
        this.textbox.connect('key-press-event', this._keyPress);

        var sw = new Gtk.ScrolledWindow ({shadow_type:Gtk.ShadowType.IN});
        sw.add (this.textbox);
        this.window.add(sw);

        this.window.show_all();
    },

    _keyPress: function(textview, event) {
        print(event, event.type, event.keyval);
        textview.buffer.text = 'ok';
        return true;
    }
}

Gtk.init (null, null);
var window = new MainWindow ();
Gtk.main ();
```

It works generally but I can not read event.keyval: console output is "undefined":

```
[union instance proxy GIName:Gdk.Event jsobj@0x7f99b1027040 native@0x1dfeab0] undefined undefined
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: try this: `_keyPress: function(self, textview, event)`

Answer (score 2):

`Gdk.Event` does not contain properties `type` or `keyval` and that's why they are `undefined`. It hasn't been around for that long, but now there is documentation available for GObject Introspection bindings to Gjs at https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs.

From your print out you see that `event` is a `Gdk.Event` and the documentation for that is at https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Gdk-3.0/Gdk.Event.html. There you can see that there are function `get_event_type` and `get_keyval`. The first returns a `Gdk.EventType` (https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Gdk-3.0/Gdk.EventType.html) and the latter an array where the second element contains a numeric code for the pressed key. You can compare the numeric keys to constants in Clutter that begin with `KEY_`.

For example add some imports to the top of your code

```
var Gdk = imports.gi.Gdk;
var Clutter = imports.gi.Clutter;
```

and change the logging line to

```
print(event,
      event.get_event_type() === Gdk.EventType.KEY_PRESS, 
      event.get_keyval()[1] === Clutter.KEY_Escape);
```

to get some sensible output.

Comment: hi, it seems dead link

Comment: The new place to find GJS docs is https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/, hopefully longer lived since it's in an official place and not an individual persons place.